# Self.request.cookies.get is not returning complete value of the cookie in google app engine

Tags: cookies, google-app-engine-python

I am setting the cookie value to (id, hash_of_id), but when the code is reading the value of the cookie it is getting only the part before comma. Not sure why:

These are the codes:

This is setting the values of the cookie named user_id.

> self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'user_id = %s; Path=/'
>   % id_hash)

The value of id_hash is coming from following:

> def make_hash(user_id): return hmac.new(SECRET,
>   str(user_id)).hexdigest()
>
> def new_hash(user_id): id_hash = make_hash(user_id) return "%s,%s"
>   %((user_id), id_hash)
>
> id_hash = new_hash(user.key().id())

When I am checking the value of the cookie in the browser using Edit this Cookie extension, it shows something like this:

[This shows cookie has got id and hashed value of id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5wmK.png)

Now value of cookie is being read:

> cookiess = self.request.cookies.get('user_id')

When I am displaying the value of variable cookiess using

> self.render("welcome.html", username = cookiess)

It shows only the part before comma,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixd9j.png)

I am not able to understand why the self.request.cookie.get returns value only till comma and not complete value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came to know that there is a bug in google appengine due to which

> self.request.cookie.get()

was returning value only till comma. Instead of comma if something else like a pipe (|) is used as separator, then this function is working properly.